# Running an infinite Python script while connected to database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, architecture, daemon

I'm working on a project to learn Python, SQL, Javascript, running servers -- basically getting a grip of full-stack. Right now my basic goal is this:

I want to run a Python script infinitely, which is constantly making API calls to different services, which have different rate limits (e.g. 200/hr, 1000/hr, etc.) and storing the results (ints) in a database (PostgreSQL). I want to store these results over a period of time and then begin working with that data to display fun stuff on the front. I need this to run 24/7. I'm trying to understand the general architecture here, and searching around has proven surprisingly difficult. My basic idea in rough pseudocode is this:

```
database.connect()
def function1(serviceA):
  while(True):
    result = makeAPIcallA()
    INSERT INTO tableA result;
    if(hitRateLimitA):
       sleep(limitTimeA)
def function2(serviceB):
  //same thing, different limits, etc.
```

And I would ssh into my server, run `python myScript.py &`, shut my laptop down, and wait for the data to roll in. Here are my questions:

- Does this approach make sense, or should I be doing something completely different?
- Is it considered "bad" or dangerous to open a database connection indefinitely like this? If so, how else do I manage the DB?
- I considered using a scheduler like `cron`, but the rate limits are variable. I can't run the script every hour when my limit is hit say, 5min into start time and has a wait time of 60min after that. Even running it on minute intervals seems messy: I need to sleep for persistent rate limit wait times which will keep varying. Am I correct in assuming a scheduler is not the way to go here?
- How do I gracefully handle any unexpected potentially fatal errors (namely, logging and restarting)? What about manually killing the script, or editing it?

I'm interested in learning different approaches and best practices here -- any and all advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I actually do exactly what you do for one of my personal applications and I can explain how I do it.

I use Celery instead of cron because it allows for finer adjustments in scheduling and it is Python and not bash, so it's easier to use. I have different tasks (basically a group of API calls and DB updates) to different sites running at different intervals to account for the various different rate limits.

I have the Celery app run as a service so that even if the system restarts it's trivial to restart the app.

I use the logging library in my application extensively because it is difficult to debug something when all you have is one difficult to read stack trace. I have INFO-level and DEBUG-level logs spread throughout my application, and any WARNING-level and above log gets printed to the console AND gets sent to my email.

For exception handling, the majority of what I prepare for are rate limit issues and random connectivity issues. Make sure to surround whatever HTTP request you send to your API endpoints in try-except statements and possibly just implement a retry mechanism.

As far as the DB connection, it shouldn't matter how long your connection is, but you need to make sure to surround your main application loop in a try-except statement and make sure it gracefully fails by closing the connection in the case of an exception. Otherwise you might end up with a lot of ghost connections and your application not being able to reconnect until those connections are gone.